# Is it a good idea to install an OS as soon as it's released?

Tags: operating-systems, updates

Or is it better to wait some time so critical fixes are released? I'm thinking specifically about Windows 7, but this can apply to any OS.

Comment: Community wiki?

Comment: @jtbandes: I don't think so... does it really meet the criteria?

Comment: It seems pretty subjective, something that doesn't have a distinct answer, and might benefit from wikification.

Comment: OK I understand.

Comment: I'm going to! I can't wait for Windows 7! My Windows Vista Machine days are numbered :) Now I am sure my job is finally going to upgrade from 2000 to Vista when Windows 7 is released :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd wait a couple of weeks at least to see what the reaction was. With Betas and Release Candidates people might be more forgiving in their assessment. Coupled with this is the fact that people won't really using it on a daily basis for "real" computing. So reports of reliability and usability might be skewed. Beta and RC users tend to be the more tech savvy users with spare machines and be prepared to rebuild those machines at a moments' notice.

When you've got the views of more "everyday" users you should be able to get a better idea of what the OS will be like for you.

You'll also be able to see how many bugs have been reported and how many patches have been released.

Unless you're developing software for release in 6-12 months (as your software will need to be able to run on Windows 7) you'd be better off waiting.

Comment: Windows XP was undeniably better once SP2 came out, and many companies waited at least for SP1. 7 was a much more polished product from the get go. While there were some issues at the outset, they were relatively minor. Generally speaking, it is best to wait at least a month, if you need to be at the cutting edge, and a good rule of thumb is generally 1 year or SP1 if you're looking for a reasonable balance of safety and agressive upgrading.

Answer (score 3):

I usually install new releases of Mac OS X as soon as they come out (I do software development, so I like to be on the cutting edge with OS updates), but I have a few things going in my favor in my case:

- I'm not using my personal computer as a production server, so security and other possible flaws are not absolutely critical.
- I'm highly competent with computers, so I'm resourceful enough to deal with most issues that arise.
- I have my old install disks from previous versions to save me if something goes really wrong.

I'd say, if any of those are *not* true for you, you probably *shouldn't* upgrade immediately; instead, wait until the general population has had their hands on it for at least a couple weeks.

Answer (score 2):

This question is subjective. To install a brand new initial OS release on say for instance a production server, it would make sense not to until a more 'stable' or proven 'reliable' build is available. That is, when bugs, security holes and other complications are highlighted and removed. Having said that, if testing or a developer and not running anything mission critical, then yes.

Comment: Why down vote..?

Answer (score 2):

As with any important software, you don't take chances *unless* the new version has a [bugfix|feature] that you really need. This is a business decision. A developer might want to install a beta, but a production typesetting shop (to pick an example at random) needs stability first. Use cases which hold people's lives in hand are even more demanding.

How long you wait is also a cost/benefit problem. Are there new goodies that will make you more productive? How much risk of loss of productivity can you afford? The reputation of the author/team/manufacturer may factor into this decision. Also the ease with which you expect to be able to deploy later updates in the event that there *is* a problem.

If you have a heterogeneous environment, you can always ease the new system in around the corners to work out the kinks before you go for a full blown change over.

Answer (score 1):

Many people prefer waiting for the first service pack before using an O/S, just in case, if they can afford to wait.

Comment: Or even SP2....

Answer (score 0):

Specifically in terms of Windows 7.  You'll most likely find the most stable 1st realese of an OS Microsoft has ever produced.
1) 7 is basically Vista 2 (in fact the build number is actually 6.x)
2) Microsoft has had Windows 7 out for the public for quite a while, so developers have already been making all drivers and software ready for 7 for months. Plus Vista code still runs on 7.

If your running Vista you'll be better off upgrading to 7.  If your running XP or something else, check the system requirements first.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I'd advise against it, in the case of XP/Vista/7 I'd say jump on the band-wagon, XP is too old, and other people have too many issues with Vista - 7 is perfectly capable for day-to day stuff.

There are one or two games that are misbehaving but they're old.

Generally you're best waiting for a few months for consumer OS, the noise flying around Snow-Leopard confirms this.

The exception is probably the Linux family, if you wait 6 months for Ubuntu, the next version will be out. If you're running FOSS, just sit on the latest stable release, don't get behind.